# Manganese(VII) oxidation state

Tags: electronic-configuration, transition-metals

A transition element is one which forms one or more stable ions which have partially filled d-orbitals. Manganese (Mn) could have an oxidation state of 7+, which means that it will lose all of the $\ce{3d^5}$ and $\ce{4s^2}$ electrons. So how could it make a 7+ ion in that case (which means that it will lose all of the $\ce{4s^2}$ and $\ce{3d^5}$ electrons) and still be defined as a transition element?

Comment: It has plenty of other transition states too. Look back at your definition.

Comment: It would be permanganate - it's impossible to have bare +7 cation, even +3 would be problematic - probably not really bare even if it would seem so.

Comment: yeah i know that manganese has various states, does it depend to whats covalently bonded to manganese atom (how much of its outer electrons are shared).?

Comment: Yes, you're right.

Answer (score 3):

The fact that manganese has a stable oxidation state in which it has (formally) lost all its $d$ electrons does not mean that it cannot be considered a transition metal, because it still has a lot of [other oxidation states](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manganese#Chemical_properties) (like +II in $\ce{Mn^2+}$ or +VI in $\ce{MnO4^2-}$) with partially filled $d$ orbitals. Moreover, a naked $\ce{Mn^7+}$ ion does not exist in solution, it is only stable in the form of the oxocomplex $\ce{MnO4-}$.