# Why are compounds of V5+ and Cr6+ colored?

Tags: coordination-compounds, transition-metals, color

As far as my knowledge goes, transition metal complex ions show a color due to a transfer of electrons between the levels of split $\mathrm d$-orbitals. In the case of $\ce{V^5+}$ and $\ce{Cr^6+}$ however, there are no electrons in the $\mathrm d$-orbitals, and the electronic configuration of both is similar to $\ce{Ar}$, yet $\ce{V^5+}$ and $\ce{Cr^6+}$ show color(yellow/brown and orange respectively).

Comment: "In the case of V5+ and Cr6+ however, there are no electrons in the d-orbitals" - maybe you could get such ions using gamma rays or sth but no compound has naked cation with such high charge

Comment: http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/28069/manganese-vii-oxidation-state

Comment: http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/39829/how-can-the-intense-color-of-potassium-permanganate-be-explained-with-molecular

Answer (score 9):

Firstly, a note about terminology. As Mithoron noted, the naked ions $\ce{V^5+}$ and $\ce{Cr^6+}$ do not exist because they require a prohibitively large amount of energy to make (just take the sum of the first 5 or 6 ionisation energies of V/Cr to see why). As such your question should really be asking about the vanadium(V) and chromium(VI) oxidation states, which can exist in acidic solution as the oxoanions $\ce{VO2+}$ and $\ce{Cr2O7^2-}$ respectively. The same idea can be extended to the manganese(VII) oxidation state, which exists as $\ce{MnO4^-}$.

Now, on to the question itself. As you rightly note, the central atom in these oxidation states have the same electronic configuration as argon; we usually call it a $\mathrm{d^0}$ configuration to indicate that there are no d electrons. The colours of these species therefore cannot arise from d-d transitions, which are the transfer of electrons from one metal orbital to another metal orbital. They are actually associated with electron transfer from the *ligand* (in this case, $\ce{O^2-}$) to the central metal atom. The name for this is [ligand-metal charge transfer (LMCT)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charge-transfer_complex).

Comment: Vanadium in the +5 oxidation state also exists as $\ce{VF5}$.